# Slope of a regression line using numpy/pandas

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a piece of code that given two lists of numbers, finds the [beta coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_(finance)). This can be done by finding the slope of the line or by using the covariance of the two lists. I tried `np.cov()` but it gave me different results than I was expecting (the value should be close to 1). Excel's [`slope` function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/slope.php) is calculating it correctly but I'm trying to do the same thing in numpy. How can I calculate the slope with many points similar to what the excel function does?

```
# both of these are lists (same size) of numbers 
bmreturns = merged['Close-bm'].pct_change()
stockreturns = merged['Close-s'].pct_change()

# incorrect value (too small) - maybe because it's normalized
print(bmreturns.cov(stockreturns))

##=SLOPE({2,4,6}, {10,20,30}) = 0.2
```

Comment: could you show a minimal example of your code?

Comment: @vlizana The two lists I have both have a length of > 400 so I can't paste it all here with the expected output. An example would be the slope function I linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading the [WikiPedia page on simple regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) it becomes clear that

beta = cov(x,y) / var(x)

You only compute cov(x,y) but dont divide by var(x)

A solution would be

```
bmreturns.cov(stockreturns) / bmreturns.var()
```